# How to generate DTD from an xml file in Python?

Tags: python, xml, dtd

I need to generate DTD file from an xml file. I tried to use some software like Oxygen, but the file looks too large to be executed. Is there a way to do it with Python?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer that involves Python, but you mentioned using oXygen so a java based command line option should work.

Try `DTDGenerator` that was developed by Saxon: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html

I tested it on a modified version of the XMark "standard.xml" file that was 385MB and it took about 5 seconds to create the DTD. (http://www.xml-benchmark.org/downloads.html)